# Overflow:hidden backlink - Does google see?

Tags: google, googlebot, backlinks

I've posted the backlink to my website with slots and casino games with such code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="lotusLeft bidiAware" style="width:80%;overflow:hidden;" onclick="window.open('http://lalalala-blablabla.html');">example.com: anchor words</a>
```

...in a closed for free watchings profile. I mean to see my profile ppl need to register own account.

Does google see and count such type links?

Comment: Are you trying to be spammy or game the system? Google will see this and probably will not like it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking about creating back links that you control, or the fact that the link requires JavaScript, or if the style on the link effects it somehow.     You also need to improve the grammar.   I don't know what you mean by "closed for free watchings profile".

Answer (score 2):

Here's the thing, using `overflow:hidden;` works as part of styling i.e. users visiting your website. Google bots, on the other hand, aren't just rendering the page but they look at source code too! So, rather than trying to game the system, its better to follow general guidelines.

Good luck!